# Is it a good practise store Thread in the Hashmap?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

I create a Hashmap xxx
store all Thread inside Hasmap 
when Thread finish , will remove it

is it a good practise?

Here is my code : https://gist.github.com/extralam/756484718c9e0cd57ddb

Comment: You should read Java PDF for thread management.

Comment: @LavekushAgrawal Why does it have to be a PDF? If you have a link, you should post it...

Comment: Its opinion based question might be possible it will closed.

Comment: @AnubianNoob This is a question for this site I think. Anyway, the question is very low quality and specific code should be past here.

Comment: Ok, the underlying question could be appropriate if asked well...

Comment: This question really needs to explain what the problem that is trying to be solved is. It might be a reasonable thing to do, it probably isn't, but it might be.

Answer (score 3):

The right way, since Java5, is the use of the [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).